# All matricies of the form T*T or TT* are Hermitian. But all all Hermitian matricies decomposable into a T*T?

Tags: linear-algebra

$(T^\dagger T)^\dagger  = T^\dagger T$ so clearly any $T^\dagger T$ is hermitian. But can any hermitian matrix be broken decomposed $T^\dagger T$?

What would  $TT^\dagger $ be to a matrix  $T^\dagger T$?

Answer (score 3):

No.  Only positive semi-definite Hermitian operators are so representable. The $1\times1$ matrix whose only entry is $-1$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

No. As a trivial one dimensional example, consider $\begin{pmatrix}-1\end{pmatrix}$ If $A^*A=\begin{pmatrix}-1\end{pmatrix}$, then $A=\begin{pmatrix}z\end{pmatrix}$, and $-1 = z\bar{z}=|z| \ge 0$, which is impossible.

More generally, the problem is that $T^*T$ is positive semidefinite, which means that $\langle x,T^*Tx\rangle \ge 0$ for any $x\in V$ where $V$ is our vector space. To see this, observe that
$$\langle x,T^*Tx \rangle = \langle Tx, Tx\rangle = \|Tx\|^2\ge 0$$
for any $x$. However there are plenty of Hermitian matrices that are not positive semidefinite, like the one dimensional example I gave above.